How can I access the files in Jfrog artifactory using python?
I was writing a code to check if a certain jar is present in jfrog artifactory or not. However I was getting 403 status code. I checked the JFrog rest API documentation and it said we need to use access tokens. however I am still facing the same issue. Here is the code that I have written
import requests

def check_artifactory():
    url = "artifactoryURLwhere my jars are present"
    access_token = "access token generated by the Jfrog"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if(response.status_code==200):
      return True
    else:
      return False

def main():
    if check_artifactory():
        print("Yes, the jar is there!")
    else:
        print("No, the jar is not there!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

